# How to exclude tests from PIT mutation analysis?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm in a drawn-out situation now with a difficult project where a significant part was refactored and checked in with a significant number of failing tests.

I run PIT in maven but I haven't been able to for a long time because the tests have to be green, but I want the PIT overview at least on the tests that do run.

What's the most effective way to isolate the failing tests from PIT?

Comment: Why tests fail, are there bugs in code or tests are deprecated ?

Comment: @PawełAdamski functionality is broken. I haven't tried deprecating tests - what effect does that have?

Comment: By deprecated tests I mean those that fails because they were written for  old code and don't work with refactored one.

Comment: @PawełAdamski I'd say the tests are broken, but not deprecated. I thought you mean there was some functionality in JUnit when you tag a test as deprecated. So the tests were definitely written against the old code, and definitely don't work with the new code, but they need fixing, not deprecating - which is a significant task that is taking time to get done, hence my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create [JUnit category](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html) **'PIT_SKIP'** and mark all failing test with it. After that you can set `excludedGroups` property in PIT maven configuration to filter out selected tests.

You can also go in opposite direction and create category **'PIT_OK'** and use property `includedGroups`.

PIT Maven plugin [documentation](http://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I looked at the 'Maven Quick Start' page and on account of its title, decided it wouldn't tell me anything except how to get started :S

Comment: Yes, we have very long "quick starts", but no documentation.